# Combine Richfaces 4 with OpenFaces 3

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, openfaces

[OpenFaces FAQ page](https://sites.google.com/a/teamdev.com/openfaces-support/documentation/openfaces-faq#TOC-Compatibility) says:

> OpenFaces 3.0 is waiting for the readiness of JSF 2.0 enabled RichFaces 4, and doesn't have critical compatibility problems with the current RichFaces 4 Milestone 3.

Does any proof of concept exist that this will work in a productive environment? We would like to combine these to frameworks in order to use OpenFaces' data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSF 2 version of RichFaces 4 has been going for years. Took them a long time to release anything, but they are now up to 4.3.2, which is I think two years past Milestone 3. Looks like OpenFaces, or at least its web page, is out of date. However after several years' experience with RichFaces, I would counsel you to look at something better, OpenFaces by itself for example, PrimeFaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually as was notice above, OF main page is out of date now. Release build is out of date too, so you need to use last nightly build, which is up to date. I don't know a lot of compatibility problems between OF and RF. You can easy use them together, but notice that officially OF supports Mojara 2.1.12 now, so you could get some problems in the case if you use other mojara version for compatibility with RF.